# Kivy android service in background and customization

Tags: android, python, service, kivy

In Kivy you can start an android service using [AndroidService mechanism](http://kivy.org/planet/2014/01/building-a-background-application-on-android-with-kivy/) from python-for-android. But how can I customize this Service? In exact:

- change the icon of the permanent  notification
- not show the notification at all (even if means that I need to make in background)
- change the text and description from the service itself (let's say I want to use the permanent notification for showing some information, which could be updated inside of the service)